# jsoup retrieving text from a div with only a class

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the text "Casual Dining" from the webpage

https://www.opentable.com//r/romanos-macaroni-grill-fort-collins?avt=eyJ2IjoxLCJtIjoxLCJwIjowLCJjIjowfQ&corrId=2b2727e6-ad4c-4958-90a6-b9f55623ab1c

I've been using:

```
Document mainPage = Jsoup.connect(addTo.getUrl()).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
    Elements content = mainPage.select("div._16c8fd5e._1f1541e1");  
                Element link = content.first();
                String out = link.text();
```

While that doesn't give me an error, it also doesn't give me the text I want.

I'm doing this for multiple similar webpages automatically, so as long as the class is the same I can get the type of restaurant text for each webpage.

How exactly do I narrow the focus of what I'm scraping down to just that text when I only have a class to go on?

Comment: Can you add how are you loading the document (mainPage)

Comment: also first div returns "View details".
"Casual Dining" is in the second div

Comment: <div class="_16c8fd5e _1f1541e1">Casual Dining</div> im (or atleast i think i am) grabbing the class that has the text "casual dining." i could just be 100% misunderstanding how this works.  also, updated to include my document creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple divs that have `._16c8fd5e ._1f1541e1` classes in that web, then you select all those divs with your select, not only one. Instead you can search by text content like this

```
String text = mainPage.select("span:contains(Dining Style)")
                   .parents().get(0).siblingElements().get(0)
                   .selectFirst("div").text();
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: i get Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'p:contains (Dining Style)': unexpected token at ':contains (Dining Style)

Comment: @JamesFrankovich ups! it was a blank space in `contains (Dining Style)`. I removed it and updated my answer. Sorry

Comment: that seems to have worked, although i dont know why using span gets me the correct element. wish there was a more comprehensive guide on jsoup, but ill try to continue to muddle through. Thanks for the help!